# Can anyone explain how fmincg works?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

In the Coursera machine learning course by Andrew Ng, fmincg is used for optimization frequently. I'm not getting the mechanism of it. Can anyone give overview of how it finds the minimum of any function?

Comment: I guess it was newton method for optimisation.

Comment: I'm guessing `cg` in an optimization function would stand for Conjugate Gradient. You can read about it in wikipedia or googling it.